# strange performance on galaxy note 3 with canvas

Tags: android, performance, android-canvas, galaxy

I've got a game, canvas based, hardware accelerated, on android.

The game is smooth and run at 40-50 fps on a galaxy note 1, galaxy S3.

I tested it today on a galaxy note 3... and it's quite slow... 20fps, graphics are slow and every mp3 sound play provokes a little freeze.

'pro' games with this galaxy note 3 don't have any problems.

I'm quite surprised that my game is slow with such a recent phone, but not with older ones... I probably do something wrong... any ideas  ?